# How sensitively can we detect a moon-sized mass of dark matter?

Tags: gravity, dark-matter

Suppose there is an object with the mass of the moon made entirely of dark matter. Suppose that somehow, it has the same mass density as the moon. By dark matter I mean matter that does not interact through the EM force, as well as the strong or weak force. Thus this object is bound entirely by the gravitational force.

Suppose this object is moving with an initial velocity, greater than the our solar system escape velocity. It's position is outside the solar system and its velocity vector direction is in the direction towards Earth.

At what point would the we be able to detect this object, with the equipment currently in operation on Earth? Is there a speed dependence on detection?

Would we be able to detect this object with gravitational wave detector?

Comment: Since it doesn't interact with light, it'd only be detected *if* it gravitationally lensed a background source (cf. [this post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16513) and/or [this post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203469)). You probably would be interested in [*MACHOs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massive_compact_halo_object) (not much on PSE about them though).

Comment: Current theories of what dark matter might be favor choices that are unlikely to form a compact bound system at that scale. That's not definitive, of course, because we're still waiting on validation (or lack thereof) of these notion from actual detection of the constituents of the dark matter, but I thought it should be said.

Comment: @KyleKanos I'm about to edit my question, but I was also interested in how easily this object would be detected by gravitational wave detectors.

Comment: Have we detected *anything* with gravitational wave detectors?

Comment: Nothing with any confidence.

Comment: Your best chance of detection is if it perturbs the orbit of a known body.  But that is a function of distance from that body, as well as its mass, not its distance from the earth.

Comment: Please read our [FAQ on question titles](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles).